GeoServer non-tiled WMS with Leaflet
Are non-tiled WMS layers possible in GeoServer?
I passed tiled:False option in Leaflet but I still get tiled layer.
const prew = L.tileLayer.betterWms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms", {
    layers: 'wp:layer',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    tiled:false
}).addTo(map);

I need single image because of heatmap rendering.

Maybe you need to use something like NonTiledLayer https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/6936. Examples in https://codesandbox.io/examples/package/leaflet.nontiledlayer

You can confirm that your GeoServer can do single tiles with the LayerPreview. It is an OpenLayers app that by default makes non-tiled requests.

Layer is non-tiled in GeoServer preview. I checked this box when creating layer in GeoServer.

Don't use a tiled layer if you don't want tiles

problem solved as @user30184 suggested.

Leaflet "tileLayer.betterWms" creates always tiled requests, typically 256x256 pixels. The TILED=YES|FALSE parameter is a vendor option that is specific to GeoServer https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#tiled.

Meta-tiling prevents issues with duplicated labels when using a tiled
client such as OpenLayers. When meta-tiling is used, images are
rendered and then split into smaller tiles (by default in a 3x3
pattern) before being served. In order for meta-tiling to work, the
tile size must be set to 256x256 pixels, and the tiled and tilesorigin
parameters must be specified.

So tiled=true alone does nothing if tilesorigin is not set (see also https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/283437/30184), and when tilesorigin is set, then Leaflet is still making tiled requests.
Use for example NonTiledLayer instead of tileLayer for making Leaflet to set single-tile requests https://codesandbox.io/examples/package/leaflet.nontiledlayer. There are also other plugins that support single tile request like https://github.com/heigeo/leaflet.wms.

Leaflet.wms plugin also supports single-tile WMS layers.

Thanks, answer edited.
