Circle symbols are displayed incompletely in tiled WMS
I am setting up a MapServer WMS point layer which is symbolized as circles. When I query the layer as tiles (e.g. 256x256, using the Leaflet default), it seems that each tile only includes circles from points located inside the queried extent. As a result, the circles in the Leaflet map are partially cut off. Is it possible to have MapServer consider points outside the requested extent and render circles overlapping the requested extent?
EDIT: I am looking for a server side solution which works with standard webmap implementations of third parties, not just for my own Leaflet based app. For example: would this issue be solved with WMTS, would nearby points be considered when the tiles are created?
These are two adjacent WMS tiles as received by the browser:


This is the map as rendered by Leaflet:


Make Leaflet to make single tile requests https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/481538/geoserver-non-tiled-wms-with-leaflet

For server side solution see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87116/geoserver-cutting-off-symbols-close-to-tile-edges

@TomazicM I think that one concentrated on GeoServer specific solutions that I don't think have a MapServer equivalent, so I pointed to the leaflet solution

By design, the server doesn't maintain session state, so serves each tile independent of any another image request.  The server doesn't know that you are trying to to tile the images in your client.

You might want to look at labelcache_map_edge_buffer  and tile_map_edge_buffer

@IanTurton Overlooked that.

@nmtoken tile_map_edge_buffer is very interesting, thank you much. I quickly tested it in Leaflet and it performs way better than single tile. I'll see if I can have the webserver add this parameter automatically, so that no client needs to send the parameter.
